# Crystal equivalent shard for "pp" (pretty printing)

Tags: crystal-lang

What is the Crystal equivalent shard for "pp" used in Ruby for pretty printing complex data structures ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PrettyPrint](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.21.0/PrettyPrint.html) is a part of a Crystal stdlib.

In short, you can just do `p obj` for "inspect" style output, `pp obj` for "pretty inspect" style output.

Comment: The correct answer is just `p obj`. `pp obj` will also print the expression you are printing.